# Showing unique data in the rows of report viewer

Tags: c#, asp.net, report-viewer2010

First off forgive my English, I wanted to display report using report viewer asp.net 2010,
    binding data to report viewer & display report data it works great, but hiding duplicates data in the group is not working, & i did right click on text box & F4 set hide duplicates with group name.It'll only hides with continuously repeat row data

```
 for example 
    Data in the column is 
    <br />Employee
    <br />Employee
    <br />Employee
    <br />Employee
    means it'll show only one time. if it is like 
    <br />Employee
    <br />Department
    <br />College
    <br />Employee
    <br />Department
    <br />College
    means it'll display same format as above.
    & here also i need get unique data in the group.
<br>
Why am asking this means i can't apply distinct in query because it is Many to many relationship query, for that i need to get uniqueness in report only please help me thanks in advance.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had to do this very thing recently.  The rdlc has something called row groups.  I believe this is what you are looking to do.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to do the optimization from the query rather than trying it out in the report viewer. When we consider the query, you may remove the duplicates using 'GROUP BY' instead of using 'DISTINCT'. Hope this helps.

Comment: Group in my case some what difficultly because its many to many relationship in table for example 10 of the same material issued to 2 products & in that products we'll choose product series machine we need to replace the damaged material.